# Retrieve Databound List<T> from ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, databound

So here's a question that's either so extremely simplistic that it has never been asked before or else it has been asked before, but I'm asking the question wrongly.

So say I am databinding a `List<MyObject>` to a `ListBox` control in a **WinForm**.

Like so:

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
// add some MyObjects to list...
myListBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null);
```

Then say I later want to obtain access to that databound list.

I thought that something like this would work...

```
List<MyObject> results = (List<MyObject>)myListBox.DataSource;
```

In Visual Studio, I can clearly see that the `DataSource` property of `myListBox` contains a List of `MyObjects`, however, the cast results in an `InvalidCastException`.

Is there an effective way to accomplish this? Or should I just hold onto the original list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myListBox.DataSource` is a `BindingSource`, not the `List<T>`.  You need to get the binding source, then extract out the data from the [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.list.aspx) property:

```
var bs = (BindingSource)myListBox.DataSource;
List<MyObject> results = (List<MyObject>)bs.List;
```

Comment: Worked like charm! I saw the `List` property of `DataSource` when I was stepping through the code, but I didn't quite know how to get a hold of it. Thank you very much!